# extend an offset background color across screen to the right

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a header, where the logo and menu are centered in the page, however the background color of the menu div is extended across to the right side of the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/gKnuY/777/,

HTML

```
<div id="wrap" align="center">
    <div id="header" >
        <div class="header-logo">
            Logo Here
        </div>
        <div class="header-menu">
            ABOUT | CARREERS | PRODUCTS | SOMTETHING | OTHER
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

THE CSS

```
*{
    margin:0px;
}
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 70px;} 

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -70px; 
    height: 70px;
    background-color:#383838;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px 5px #cacaca;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px 5px #cacaca;
    clear:both;} 
#header {
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:960px;
}
.header-logo {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#654654;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
.header-menu {
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#383838;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 30px 5px 0px #cacaca;
    box-shadow:  0px 30px 5px 0px #cacaca;
}
```

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/gKnuY/778/show/

Comment: yeah thats it, thanks mate

Comment: Okay I'll add my answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the main container of your header you need to make it expand 100% while having it `left` a certain amount.

**This is what I changed**

```
#header {
  height:100px;
  left: 40%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #383838;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/gKnuY/779/show/)